# copy all workbook sheets to a new workbook VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code to copy every sheet in a workbook to a new one and it works fine but it reverses the order of the sheets, would there be anyway to keep it from doing this?

```
Sub copy()

'copies all the sheets of the open workbook to a new one
Dim thisWb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In wbTemp.Worksheets
    ws.Delete
Next
On Error GoTo 0

For Each ws In thisWb.Sheets
    ws.copy After:=wbTemp.Sheets(1)
Next
wbTemp.Sheets(1).Delete

'save vba code here
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show Range("CA1").Text & "- (Submittal) " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy") & "_" & Format(Time, "hhmm") & ".xlsx"



LetsContinue:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume LetsContinue

End Sub
```

I'm copying all the sheets so i can save it as a different file extension and this was the only way i found that worked.

Workbook before it copies
[image]

Workbook after it copies
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Scott Craner's comment, which OP replied to indicating it worked:

> Change
>
> ```
> ws.copy After:=wbTemp.Sheets(1)
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> ws.copy After:=wbTemp.Sheets(wbTemp.Worksheets.Count)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the file format

> (I'm copying all the sheets so i can save it as a different file extension and this was the only way i found that worked.)

Then you can try this code:

```
Sub Test()
    fn = Range("CA1").Text & "- (Submittal) " & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yy_hhmm")
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=fn, fileFilter:="Excel Workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    If fileSaveName <> False Then
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileSaveName, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```