# How do I save a worksheet to a new workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, save

I am trying to save a single worksheet to a new workbook (VBA should create a new workbook).

The code is running and the new workbook is popping up with the needed data and the save as dialogue window also opens but when I select the name and save the file it is no where to be found the the new workbook stays open as (Book1 or whatever auto populates).

I would like for a Save As name to auto populate when the dialogue window opens and have it referencing to two cells (i.e. $A$11, $B$11) in the original workbook.

Here is my VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveConsolidatedDemandData()
    ' Macro2 Macro
    'Dim NameFile As Variant
            'With Worksheets("SO1")
            'NameFile = .Range("M3") & "_" & .Range("C11") & "_" & .Range("B22") & ".xls"
    'End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '
    '
        Sheets("Consolidation").Select
        Sheets("Consolidation").Copy
        Application.GetSaveAsFilename


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Check out this link: [copy all workbook sheets to a new workbook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094057/copy-all-workbook-sheets-to-a-new-workbook-vba)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a macro showing/doing what you are asking for. Change the workbook name as well as sheet name as needed:

```
Sub test()
Dim wb, wbnew As Workbook 
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim filename As String

Set wb = Workbooks(2)  'Name of the workbook you are copying from
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Name of sheet you are copying
filename = ws.Range("A11") & "_" & ws.Range("B11")& ".xlsm"
'adds new workbook
Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add
wb.Activate

'copies sheet to new workbook
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=wbnew.Sheets(1)

'Save as dialog box to save as excel file
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show filename

wbnew.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: This gives a 'subscript out of range' error for me. I had to use `After` instead of `Before`. when copying to the new workbook.