# Add an excel sheet as attachment on outlook email with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to send an entire Sheet `("SEND")` from my excel file as an attachment using VBA, I have used the following code to accomplish it:

I'm getting the following error: The variable of the object or the variable 'with' was not defined,
what is wrong with the code?

```
Sub Sendemail()
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim tempFile As String
Dim strbodymsg As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim tempWB As Workbook

tempFile = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\sheets_copy.xlsx"

Set wb = wb.Sheets("SEND")
wb.Save
wb.Sheets(Array("SEND")).Copy
Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook

If Len(Dir(tempFile)) <> 0 Then
    Kill tempFile
End If

' Save & close the tempFile
tempWB.SaveAs tempFile
tempWB.Close

strbody = "Hello"
 
'Create Outlook email
Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
    
On Error Resume Next
With xEmailObj
    .Display
    .To = "email1@gmail.com"
    .Cc = "email2@gmail.com"
    .Subject = "Email Test"
    .Attachments.Add tempFile
    .HTMLBody = strbody
    If DisplayEmail = False Then
        '.Send
    End If
End With
    
On Error GoTo 0

Set xEmailObj = Nothing
Set xOutlookObj = Nothing

End Sub()
```

Comment: Works OK for me, after adding `Dim xOutlookObj As Object` of course. You must have left that out of your copy/paste?

Comment: you are right, i just forgot to copy it, but here at my computer it is not working

Comment: i will try again at work tomorrow see if works there

Comment: I did get an error here... `Set wb = wb.Sheets("SEND")` - as you are trying to set a `Worksheet` object to a `Workbook` variable... and you are trying to use wb before setting it to anything valid... maybe try fixing those things first? (I commented those things out initially as you said the problem was with your `With` statement.) You may also want to include an `Option Explicit` and remove that error handling.

Comment: And keep in mind that you do not attach a `Worksheet`, you attach a `Workbook` - make sure you understand the difference between the 2 things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save a worksheet to a new workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45334469/how-do-i-save-a-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Sendemail()
Dim xOutlookObj As Object
Dim xEmailObj As Object
Dim tempFile As String
Dim strbodymsg As String
Dim wb As Workbook
strbody = "Hello"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SEND").Copy
Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook 'previous command opens instantly

' First you can only save the file as.

tempWB.SaveAs filename:=""

'variable from userform or string outputs into default documents folder as xls

'Create Outlook email=============
Set xOutlookObj =                 
CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set xEmailObj = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
    With xEmailObj
        .Display
        .To = "email1@gmail.com"
        .Cc = "email2@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Email Test"
        .Attachments.Add tempWB.FullName      
'previously saved workbook with single sheet
    .HTMLBody = strbody
    If DisplayEmail = False Then
        '.Display
        '.Send
    End If
End With
'then dealing with the "tempfile"
tempWB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
Kill tempWB.FullName
tempWB.Close savechanges:=False  'first kill then close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set xEmailObj = Nothing
Set xOutlookObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

I think your problem is already solved by now. But I post my modification of your code. For me it works.